# Handlebars.js - loop an array excluding the first element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, handlebars.js

For a bootstrap carousel item `<div class="item">` the first item needs to be active

`div class="item active">` though *only* the first the item

Thought to write a Handlebars Helper, to loop through like this:

```
  <div class="item active">
    <div class="foo">{{foo.[0]}}</div>
  </div>
{{#each resArray foo}}
  <div class="item">
    <div class="foo">{{this}}</div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

..though how would this be written correctly?

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("resArray", function(array) {
  return array[1 to array.length];
});
```

Also, where would this helper go? ..in my node server.js file where Handlebars is assigned?

Answer (score 18):

Turns out it's as easy as:

```
{{#each foo}}
  {{#if @first}}
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="foo">{{this}}</div>
    </div>
  {{else}}
    <div class="item">
      <div class="foo">{{this}}</div>
    </div>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

```
{{#each foo}}
  <div class="item {{#if @first}}active{{/if}}">
    <div class="foo">{{this}}</div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```